# UX for Model with Children in Admin Panel

Tags: laravel, user-interface, laravel-5.6, user-experience

I would like everyones input on how to layout a CRUD for an admin panel. First, the 'basic' data layout:

```
- tblSchool (parent)
- tblCars
- tblContacts (eg: John/Mary/Joe)
- tblContactType (eg: Admin/Manager/Accounts)
- tblContactDetails (eg: 012-345-6789/john@place.com)
- tblContactDetailTypes (eg: Telephone/Facsimilie/Mobile/Email)

- pivotTblCars (connect tblSchool with tblCars)
- pivotTblContacts (connect tblSchool with tblContacts)
```

Firstly, pivot tables are there for referrential integrity and there are other (parents) which share the same details and hence the need for the pivot tables.

So standard CRUD would just be a separate page for each element type, each having its own index, create, edit, and possibly show page.

**1)** So one approach for example could be: 'School' index would have a grid of all the schools - then you would select a school and click a 'manage contacts' button to get taken to the 'Contacts' index page where you would manage all the contacts of the selected School. Then you would have to go 'back' to then either manage another schools contacts and/or its 'Cars'.

**2)** Another approach could be that when a School is selected, sub grids below the school grid could load the children (car/contacts) data. This seems disconnected and unintuitive though.

**3)** Another approach could be that you would 'view' a school to see its data and at the same time it would be the index/grids for the 'Cars' and 'Contacts' below its data?

How would you handle a more inclusive approach with less steps/better flow?

Comment: Why not list all contacts and filter, sort, etc. by the school to refine? Then it's just a matter of viewing the contact details and making any updates, etc.

Comment: While a modal would be nice, its not adding much to the solutions provided above. I ended up going with the parent_grid with a 'view' button that takes you to a page with a slim column on the left with the parent data and then the bulk of the right reserved for the child_data grid, changed by tab headings at the top.

Answer (score 1):

**4)** why not use a modal, on which the main page would have the grid of all school with its details, except that cars details and contacts details are just link in which upon clicking will pop a modal instead of redirecting to a new page.

main reason for this,

1. this will improve the request speed as you would just request for a data.
2. this is more user-friendly approach, and a better-experience for the end-user, as the page will not reload/redirect to another page.